# Android - Extracting the name of Shortcuts

Tags: android, android-intent

I have searched and searched, but for some reason people only seam to be creating shortcuts in their apps, rather than using them. And Google does not provide much info on this either, only how to create them.

In an app that I have, I am creating the possibility of adding a shortcut to some actions in the app. Selecting the shortcut is simple enough, and after this I am storing the Intent as a Uri in preferences.

I want to extract the list of selected shortcut's and display them. Converting them back to Intents for launch is simple, but displaying them seams not to be. I cannot find anything about extracting the name of these. And I would rather display the name of the shortcut rather than the name of the application it belongs to (Which is the only thing that I am able to get).

Anyone know how to get the name of a Shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

> I have searched and searched, but for some reason people only seam to be creating shortcuts in their apps, rather than using them.

There is no concept of "shortcuts" in Android.

> And Google does not provide much info on this either, only how to create them.

Certain home screen implementations may support shortcuts. Because Google happened to define a means for creating such shortcuts in their own home screen (albeit outside of the Android SDK), their `Intent` action for this (`com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT`) has become a convention. However, AFAICT, that is the only aspect of shortcuts that appears to be standardized among the hundreds of home screen implementations.

> Anyone know how to get the name of a Shortcut?

If you are the author of the home screen, and you are the one responding to the `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` broadcasts, it is your job to store the name and everything that you need to display the shortcuts to the user.

If you are not the author of the home screen, you have no idea whether anything reacted to your `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` broadcast, let alone have any means of retrieving that data. Certain home screen implementations might offer a richer shortcut API that you could leverage, but only a small percentage of Android device owners would be using those home screens.

Comment: I use INSTALL_SHORTCUT to launch an ActivityForResult. Like I mentioned above, I do get a selection of shortcuts. I also manage to convert this into an Uri, but I cannot get the names from anywhere, not even from the original intent within the onActivityResult(). According to Google (And others on this site), there should be a name within the Extras data, but it does not seam to be the case.